# qticon only showing on my pc

Tags: c++, qt

i made an app in the tray bar with an icon with qt, this is the way i make the icon;

```
trayIcon->setIcon(QIcon("favicon.ico"));
```

but it only show the icon on my pc, when i give the project to somebody else its just invisible.
even if i do the next thing;

```
trayIcon->setIcon(QIcon(QDir::currentPath() + "/favicon.ico"));
```

does somebody know this problem? / how to solve it? THNX!!!

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure you have deployed the favicon.ico to the other computers? I recommend that you put the favicon.ico file to the resource file. [More information about Qt resource system.](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/resources.html)

If you want to keep the icon as a separate file, you could try to change QDir::currentPath() to QApplication::applicationDirPath(). The current path might not be the application path in those other computers.